# Как хранить конфиденциальные текстовые данные?

Tags: защита, php, шифрование, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как рекомендуется хранить конфиденциальные данные типа VARCHAR в СУБД MySQL?

Есть информация о людях (ФИО, адрес, номер моб. телефона и т.д.). Необходимо защитить эти данные с сохранением возможности поиска по LIKE. Какие методы шифрования для этого существуют (желательно с реализацией на PHP)?

Comment: @undestroyer, вы не сможете искать по like после шифрования, вам придется дешифровать каждую строчку.

Comment: @Etki, единственно приемлемыми методами нашел смещение по ключу и замену по словарю, но в наше время это вообще не серьезно

Comment: @atom-22, вы не на то тратите свое время. Даже если вы зашифруете данные в MySQL суперстойким алгоритмом с возможность поиска по LIKE, но оставите дырку в PHP приложении, позволяющую сделать эксплоит -- вся ваша работа пойдет на смарку.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно воспользоваться MySQL-функциями симметричного шифрования, например, `AES_ENCRYPT()` и `AES_DECRYPT()`. Не бог весть что, 128-битный ключ, то все-таки защита с возможностью последующей расшифровки данных

```
INSERT INTO
  tbl
VALUES (
  NULL,
  AES_ENCRYPT('name', UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')),
  MD5('password')
);

SELECT
  AES_ENCRYPT(name, UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')) AS name
FROM
  tbl
WHERE id = 1
```

Пароль можно сразу зашифровать необратимо и при аутентификации сравнивать хэши.

Comment: А LIKE по полям зашифрованным через AES работает?)

Comment: К сожалению, нет, меры безопасности почти всегда приводят к уменьшению удобства. Как вариант, можно держать расшифрованные данные во временных таблицах. Незашифрованные данные хотя бы не будут попадать в дамп. К сожалению, MySQL не самая лучшая база данных для безопасного хранения информации.

Comment: Значит ваш ответ не верен: `Необходимо защитить эти данные с сохранением возможности поиска по LIKE`